# Es posible cambiar el color de un <input type="button"> con .hover y Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando un trabajo para clase pero no consigo cambiar el color de las letras del botón cuando el ratón esta encima o fuera del mismo. Los estilos están definidos arriba.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").hover(function(){
$(this).addClass(color1);
},function(){
$(this).addClass(color2);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente forma

```
$("input").hover(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  }, function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});
```

Comment: Recordar además que esto se puede hacer con CSS puro.

Comment: Como podría hacerse con CSS ? Gracias.

Comment: Exactamente del mismo modo, solo que debes hacerlo en estilo css... obtienes el control, la funcion, y cambias el color